# How to Debug Apache Storm Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, xdebug

I have Apache Storm setup in IntelliJ to run in local mode. I can run the starter topologies just fine. However, I'd like to know how to debug Python bolts. So as a simple example, how would one debug `splitsentences.py` for the `WordCountTopology`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `pydev` installed (or you don't mind installing it), you can debug remote applications following [this instructions](http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html).

`pydev` is quite ok if you have Java background since it is basically eclipse. Installing it is fairly straightforward following [this](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html).

In my machine, the remote debugging works for local processes. I have `pydev` installed over `Eclipse Mars`.

(I don't think this would be important, but in my case I have two different installations of `Eclipse` in my machine, one for Java and one for `pydev`.)

Hope it helps.

Comment: You're welcome. If you bump into problems, just post them.

Answer (score 1):

I can only give a "high level" answer:

Using Storm's multilang feature results in forking off a new process that executes the external code. Thus, a new `java.lang.UNIXProcess` is started that executes the `python` command as specified in WordCountTopology:

```
public SplitSentence() { super("python", "splitsentence.py"); }
```

You need to do a remote debug session and attach to this process from within Eclipse. However, as I am not familiar with Python I don't know how to remote debug Python in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That's what I figured was going on. You're comment describes what's happening better than I could have done. It doesn't quite answer the question of how to tie the process into a debugger, but hopefully, it will help in determining how to do it.

Comment: That was the intention. Hopefully it triggers somebody else... Or you start a new question "How to remote debug Python in Eclipse" ;)